# trigger java function on mysql datetime

Tags: java, mysql

I have several datetime column in my MySQL DB. I want to trigger a java function when the date is reached. At worst, trigger a MySQL function can do the job as well. How to have a trigger datetime based on MySQL without doing cron job on every minute ?

Comment: Your database would/should not be able to trigger your application, so you'd either have to use a db trigger or use some scheduler to run the function (aka job or task) at the specified time.

Comment: I'd hope to avoid each minute cron.

Comment: I don't think you have many choices,  db's are passive, you need a scheduled event (or cron job) to do this kind of thing.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a cron job/scheduler for this? That's what they are made for: track time until a certain timestamp is reached and then trigger some action. Those schedulers are generally very efficient and anything that's meant to run at a specific time uses such a scheduler at some level.

Comment: I want to update a column value when a datetime is reached and I was wondering if there is some DB mechanism that can do that. I will do it with cron (or even better scheduler if you can advise me a better one) launching a java batch, checking datetime and making update for all datetimes reached.

Answer (score 0):

Even a trigger wouldn't do the job, there must be a process to check (in your case if the date was reached)
Like Thomas said job or a task (CRON) that sets the trigger or an application to do what you wish with the database.

Comment: I'd hope to avoid each minute cron.

Answer (score 0):

It is not ideal to do this in database, but if no better choice, you can achieve it by creating a MySQL event, which is a scheduled task.

You need to add a insert and/or update trigger to the database table and create the event based on the datetime value of the column

You can create the event in the way that drops itself after it is executed at the specified time.